# The content of an appendix file is not shown

Tags: appendices

This is my main tex file `ccc.tex`:

```
\documentclass[doublespaced,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\input{chap1}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Proof of Theorem}
    \label{app:A}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This is my `chap1.tex` file:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
...
```

And here is a simple appendix file `Proof of Theorem.tex`:

```
Nothing!
```

But the output does not print the content of the appendix:

[image]

What do I miss in these files?

Comment: You have to input the appendix file also.

Comment: @Sigur: You mean I should call both `\chapter{Proof of Theorem}` and `\input{Proof of Theorem}`?

Comment: The `\chapter{}` is just to start a new chapter with its title. Its contents you have to type below or to input from some `tex` file.

Comment: You can move `\chapter{Proof of Theorem}` into the appendix `tex` file which will be inputed.

Comment: Better use `\input{ProofofTheorem}`. Don't use weird characters in file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to input the appendix file also. The `\chapter{<title here>}` command is just to start a new chapter with its title `<title here>`.

The contents of the chapter you have to type below that command or to input from some `.tex` file.

You can move `\chapter{Proof of Theorem}` into the appendix `.tex` file which will be inputed.

Finally, as pointed out by cfr, its better use `\input{file-name}` with files without blank spaces in file name.